# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (Undefined sybols for Architecture x86_64)

Tags: c++, json, clang++, vscode-debugger

Got my program working when built and I run it. Trying to link lldb to my project so I can debug my program. Whenever I try to start the debugger, this notification pops up for me:

[image]

I figure I'm not setting up my Launch.json properly, but can't deduce where that issue lies.

The following is printed out to the terminal:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "write_color(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Vec3)", referenced from:
      _main in main-1e06e3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', '/usr/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -g /Users/n3vdawg/gameDevStudies/ray_tracer_definitive/src/*.cpp -o /Users/n3vdawg/gameDevStudies/ray_tracer_definitive/ray_tracer'" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I'm using VSCode and my project is written in C++. Here's my launch.json and tasks.json The preLaunchTask is correct, I believe. I can't figure out how to format my launch.json properly and it's keeping me from debugging.

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/ray_tracer",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/ray_tracer"
              ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Included is also my file structure:

[image]

Adding write_color function:

Color.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Color.h"

void write_color(std::ofstream &out, Color pixel_color) {
    // Write the translated [0,255] value of each color component
    out << static_cast<int>(255.999 * pixel_color.x()) << ' '
        << static_cast<int>(255.999 * pixel_color.y()) << ' '
        << static_cast<int>(255.999 * pixel_color.z()) << '\n';
}
```

Color.h

```
#ifndef _COLOR_H_
#define _COLOR_H_

#include "Vec3.h"

#include <iostream>

void write_color(std::ostream &out, Color pixel_color);

#endif
```

Realized I need to include fstream and function def should expect std::ofstream

Comment: Show us the declaration and definition of that write_color function (and in which file they reside)

Comment: You should probably also invest in a decent incremental build system, as you are currently always recompiling everything.

Comment: Oh, I just realized my declarations definition is wrong. I'll fix it. Should be including `fstream` too.

Comment: @Botje Any you recommend? Any good reading material/tutorials on it too?

Comment: Cmake, xmake, or just plain makefiles, for example. There's loads more build systems to choose from, so study a few and try ones you like.

Comment: I've been using CMake on my PC. I enjoy, but I couldn't get it to work properly with Xcode, so I went with this tutorial and made sure to change some stuff up. It was a good learning experience at least! https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac